# How to ignore the documentation generated by Help file builder for Public Class or Methods?

Tags: c#, sandcastle

How can I omit certain public classes or methods from being included in the documentation generated by The SandCastle Help File Builder?

Example: I have the following public class with two public methods:

```
/// <summary>
/// A simple test class.
/// </summary>
public class MyClass
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Method1s this instance.
    /// </summary>
    public void Method1()
    {
        // Do some operations here.
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Method2s this instance.
    /// </summary>
    public void Method2()
    {
        // Do some operations here.
    }
}
```

When I generate the Help file out of this code using SandCastle Help File Builder, I want to ignore `Method2`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In your project properties in Sandcastle Help File Builder GUI, edit the `ApiFilter` property (click the "..." button) and uncheck the members you don't want to see in the help file.

Answer (score 14):

(This is an update, since the UI seems to have changed since Thomas Levesque posted his comment. It is also different than some info I've found other places online.)

In the latest version of SandCastle, as of May 31, 2014, you have to go through 3 steps to get there.

1. In the standalone UI, select the **Project Properties** tab.
2. There should be a list of categories on the left. Select **Visibility**
3. Click the **Edit API Filter** button; this is at the bottom of the from on the right side.

From there, you will find the list of API entries. You can individually deselect classes, namespaces, and items inside a class (properties, fields, methods).

Comment: Found the same stuff on the properties tab of the project in my Visual Studio 2015.